# Login Screen when authenticated should display a new activity(new screen)

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Hi I am working on firebase authentication and the user/name password should display a new activity & a new screen  when authenticated but it does not do that.I can't seem to understand what is the problem

Here is the code:
***Main.dart***

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AuthenticationService>(
          create: (_) => AuthenticationService(FirebaseAuth.instance),
        ),
        StreamProvider(
          create: (context) =>
              context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges,
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: AuthenticationWrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firebaseUser = context.watch<User>();

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      return HomePage();
    }
    return PatientList();
  }
}
```

Mainly the main.dart file has the authentication code

***HomePage.dart***

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 400,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/images/loginHeader.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FadeAnimation(
                          1.8,
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      color: Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, .2),
                                      blurRadius: 20.0,
                                      offset: Offset(0, 10))
                                ]),
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      border: Border(
                                          bottom: BorderSide(
                                              color: Colors.grey[100]))),
                                  child: TextField(
                                    controller: emailController,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      hintText: "Email or Phone number",
                                      hintStyle:
                                          TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400])),
                                ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: TextField(
                                    controller: passwordController,
                                  obscureText: true,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      hintText: "Password",
                                      hintStyle:
                                          TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400])),
                                ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          )),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 100, right: 100, top: 20, bottom: 20),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28.0),
                            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                        onPressed: () {
                          context.read<AuthenticationService>().signIn(
                                email: emailController.text.trim(),
                                password: passwordController.text.trim(),
                              );
                        },
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1),
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        child: Text("Login".toUpperCase(),
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                      ),
                      ClipOval(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            gotoForgotPassword(BuildContext context) {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => ForgotPassword()),
                              );
                            }
                            gotoForgotPassword(context);
                          },
                          child: Text("Forgot Password"),
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

This has the login screen and mostly the UI of the app it has button to navigate to other activities of the app.

```
class AuthenticationService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;

  AuthenticationService(this._firebaseAuth);

  Stream<User> get authStateChanges => _firebaseAuth.idTokenChanges();


  Future<String> signIn({String email, String password}) async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      return "Signed in";
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
  }

  Future<String> signUp({String email, String password}) async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      return "Signed up";
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea what I  am doing it wrong? some navigation issue i suppose.

When the user enters the correct username & password, it should navigate to another screen, but it doesn't. I also checked the firebase console and it is establishing the connection and telling 1  user logged IN on 17th Feb

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should use [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) widget in the **AuthenticationWrapper** class.

```
class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User>(
      stream: context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges,
      builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
        final User firebaseUser = snapshot.data;
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
         return HomePage();
        }
        return PatientList(); 
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Valdim  stream: context.watch<User>()                                                                            
 The argument type 'User' can't be assigned to parameter type stream<User>

Comment: @RishailSiddiqui oh, try this one

stream: context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges,

Comment: @RishailSiddiqui I've updated the code in the answer

Answer (score 1):

put the code in your main.dart

```
       Future<void> main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            Provider<AuthenticationService>(
              create: (_) => AuthenticationService(FirebaseAuth.instance),
            ),
            StreamProvider(
              create: (context) =>
                  context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges,
            )
          ],
          child: MaterialApp(
          //  home: AuthenticationWrapper(),
             home: StreamBuilder(
        stream:FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder:(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User>snapshot){
         if(snapshot.hasData){
          return HomePage(),
       }
    return PatientList(),
     }
     )
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: sorry but that did not have any effect